# Недопонимание с приватной статической переменной класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, static

Почему к приватной статической переменной класса я могу получить доступ из глобальной области видимости, а из функции не могу ?

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
private:
    static int a;
};

int test::a = 5;  // ОК

int main()
{
    test::a = 10;  // ОШИБКА
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет не можешь,то ты выделил для нее память а не обратился к ней.

Comment: В первом случае это инициализация, читай вызов статического конструктора, а во втором - присваивание. Чтобы меньше путаться стоит прекратить использовать `=` для инициализации.

Comment: я бы добавил, что полезно называть классы с большой буквы, а экземпляры - с маленькой.